# filter multiple conditions on array in swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I need to apply below filter combination on array of struct.

[image]

`var students:[Student]?` - on this student array need to apply combination of these filters using swift. User can select only Name or  both Name and location and so on ..mulitple combinations.

Really not sure ... how to implement this.

```
struct Student {
    var fName: String
    var lname: String
    var class: String
    var pincode: Int
    var active: Bool
    var location: Address
}

struct Address {
    var street1: String
    var street2:String
    var country:String
}
```

Suppose we need to filter based on

- Name (fname only)
- Active
- location ( street1 only bydefault )

Comment: What's the logic on Location filter? What's the entry? A text? If yes, filter on street1? country? etc. Name filtering, is on which property? `fName`? `name`? Both?

Comment: For location - may be street1 and street2  these are 2 sub filters we can apply

Comment: But what are actually filtering on, there are 2 name properties and Address contains 3 properties? Exact match, contains or…? Please clarify what you want to do and maybe supply some samples and your attempt at solving this.

Comment: So you want to be able to filter your array of `students` to select those that string match fname, address.street1, and/or active? (So the user checks one or more of those options, enters data for each selected option, and then you filter your array to find the items that match those values?)

Comment: Sub-filters? Wait, what? You can't implement something, if you haven't defined it. First you need to define what is you want to do, clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First of all I made a little bit changes to your model:

```
struct Student {
    var fName: String?
    var lname: String?
    var `class`: String?
    var pincode: Int?
    var active: Bool
    var location: Address
}
struct Address {
    var street1: String?
    var street2: String?
    var country: String?
}
```

### Building dummy objects:

```
let address1 = Address(street1: "Kiwi str", street2: nil, country: "US")
let address2 = Address(street1: "Cherry str", street2: nil, country: "GB")
let student1 = Student(fName: "Mark", lname: nil, active: false, location: address1)
let student2 = Student(fName: "Diana", lname: "Luck", active: true, location: address2)
let student3 = Student(fName: "Gaga", lname: "Merry", active: true, location: address2)
let student4 = Student(fName: "Mark", lname: "Luck", active: true, location: address1)

let students = [student1, student2, student3, student4]
```

### Filtering extension on Array with students elements:

```
extension Array where Element == Student {
    func filtered(fName: String? = nil, lName: String? = nil, active: Bool? = nil, street1: String? = nil) -> [Student] {
        students.filter { student in
            var fNameOk = false
            if let fName = fName, student.fName == fName {
                fNameOk = true
            }
            
            var lNameOk = false
            if let lName = lName, student.lname == lName {
                lNameOk = true
            }
            
            var activeOk = false
            if let active = active, student.active == active {
                activeOk = true
            }
            
            var street1Ok = false
            if let street1 = street1, student.location.street1 == street1 {
                street1Ok = true
            }
            return (
                (fName == nil ? true : fNameOk) &&
                (lName == nil ? true : lNameOk) &&
                (active == nil ? true : activeOk) &&
                (street1 == nil ? true : street1Ok)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

### Testing filtering extension:

```
let r1 = students.filtered(fName: "Diana", lName: "Luck", active: true)
let r2 = students.filtered(fName: "Mark", active: true, street1: "Kiwi str")
```

### Test output:

```
// r1
{fName "Diana", lname "Luck", nil, nil, active true, {street1 "Cherry str", nil, country "GB"}}
// r2
{fName "Mark", lname "Luck", nil, nil, active true, {street1 "Kiwi str", nil, country "US"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing code by Ramis so it would compile and would be more straightforward without unnecessary checking of nil values. Also, if one condition is false, it returns false immediately.

```
extension Array where Element == Student {
    func filter(fName: String? = nil, active: Bool? = nil, street1: String? = nil) -> [Student] {
        filter { student in
            
            if let fName = fName, student.fName != fName {
                return false
            }
            
            if let active = active, student.active != active {
                return false
            }
            
            if let street1 = street1, student.location.street1 != street1 {
                return false
            }
            
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be i.e.:

```
let address1 = Address(street1: "Kiwi str", street2: nil, country: "US")
let address2 = Address(street1: "Cherry str", street2: nil, country: "GB")
let student1 = Student(fName: "Mark", lname: nil, active: false, location: address1)
let student2 = Student(fName: "Diana", lname: "Luck", active: true, location: address2)
let student3 = Student(fName: "Gaga", lname: "Merry", active: true, location: address2)
let student4 = Student(fName: "Mark", lname: "Luck", active: true, location: address1)

let students = [student1, student2, student3, student4]

let filtered1 = students.filter(fName: "Diana", active: true)
let filtered2 = students.filter(fName: "Mark")
```